maven compile error when installing nullaway
I'm facing to a problem below.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time:  0.770 s [INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-09T09:34:45+09:00 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: 
  Fatal error compiling: error: invalid flag: -Xep:NullAway:ERROR -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

my `pom.xml` file
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uber.nullaway</groupId>
            <artifactId>nullaway</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Xplugin:ErrorProne</arg>
                        <arg>-Xep:NullAway:ERROR</arg>
                        <arg>-XepOpt:NullAway:AnnotatedPackages=com.example</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3.4</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.uber.nullaway</groupId>
                            <artifactId>nullaway</artifactId>
                            <version>0.9.7</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

and environment versions
mJP0K9VCRTDFCPC:demo 01611367$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.46+19-CA (build 17.0.9+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.46+19-CA (build 17.0.9+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
mJP0K9VCRTDFCPC:demo 01611367$ javac -version
javac 17.0.9 mJP0K9VCRTDFCPC:demo 01611367$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.9.6/libexec
Java version: 17.0.9,
vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.,
runtime: /Users/01611367/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.9-zulu/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_JP,
platform encoding: UTF-8 OS
name: "mac os x", version: "14.4.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"

This configuration is not in NullAway instructions for Maven:
<arg>-Xep:NullAway:ERROR</arg>

Remove it.

Then I get another error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred

I suspect now that the version of NullAway is too old. Try with the latest release.
